# Service Broker Msg 33305

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I restored a database from SQL Server 2014 Enterprise to SQL Server 2017 Standard.

The restore went through fine without any issues/errors.

I then run DBCC CHECKDB on the database and I get the following messages related to the service broker. Any help in understanding this is appreciated.

> Msg 8997, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Service Broker Msg 33305, State 1:
>   The multicast message body row with reference 28671 should have
>   reference count value of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been an existing problem with the database you backed up.

Do you need to preserve the existing Service Broker conversations?  Messages?  Broker Identifier?

If you don't need the Service Broker messages, or to preserve any of its conversations or place in a distributed broker topology, you might end all the conversations WITH CLEANUP, or ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER.

If you do need to fix this while preserving the other conversations and messages, you would probably need to open a support case, as there are really only a handful of people who can advise you on this.

Comment: Thanks for this David. This has given me some food for thought. I will get back on what I would be doing.